# Flat array without using FlatMap

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got array `model` and I want to use its `values`  array separetaly, since `flatMap` is not available in my angular application without adding `"esnext"` to tsconfig.json file I was wondering if it's possible to do the same result without `flatMap`. Here's my current result:

```js
var model= [
        {
          "values": [
            {
              "colId": 1,
              "value": 7086083333.333333
            },
            {
              "colId": 2,
              "value": null
            },
          ],
          "rowId": 0,
        },
        {
          "values": [
            {
              "colId": 1,
              "value": null
            },
          ],
          "rowId": 1,
          "rowHeader": ""
        },
        {
          "values": [
            {
              "colId": 1,
              "value": null
            },
            {
              "colId": 2,
              "value": null
            },
          ],
          "rowId": 2,
          "rowHeader": ""
        }
      ]
     const data = model.flatMap((wm) => wm.values);
     console.log(data);
```

Comment: There's an example in the MDN documentation ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to do that.

```js
var model = [{ "values": [{ "colId": 1, "value": 7086083333.333333 }, { "colId": 2, "value": null }, ], "rowId": 0, }, { "values": [{ "colId": 1, "value": null }, ], "rowId": 1, "rowHeader": "" }, { "values": [{ "colId": 1, "value": null }, { "colId": 2, "value": null }, ], "rowId": 2, "rowHeader": "" } ];

const data = model.reduce((arr, currentValue) => {
  return arr.concat(currentValue.values);
}, []);

console.log(data);
```